# Where is the folder location for local storage when using react

Tags: reactjs, browser

I'm trying to find the folder location of local storage when using react. Is the location specific to the browser or specific to react?

Comment: Who says it's in a folder at all? Why do you care where it is? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The location should be specific to the OS, then browser, then domain. What are you trying to do? It's probably not visible or human-readable.

Comment: just curious, I like to know where things are

Comment: In short, it's in the same folder as your browser (or in a sub-folder of that folder).  The longer answer is that the exact location varies based on the browser, and probably also operating system, so there's no good way to know. It really doesn't matter though, given that you have absolutely no control over it (unless you have write permissions on your user's computer, in which case web tech isn't even applicable).

Comment: local storage is protected, and not something you are meant to access in any other way than through your app.  The physical method of storage isn't something you can control, manipulate, or access.

Comment: Downvoters: why?  This is a perfectly legitimate question that betrays the author's misunderstanding of how local storage works.  The answer (that it doesn't work the way the OP thinks) can likely be valuable to other novices.   Please don't downvote legitimate questions, no matter how n00b-ish they might be.

Comment: @Claies If it's on-disk you can access it (your own, I mean), but the hoops you'd potentially have to jump through may make it impractical. OP just wants to know where it is- it's curiosity, a good thing.

Comment: @machineghost I don't think there's necessarily a misunderstanding-just asking where local storage lives. It lives *somewhere*. Whether it's practical to *do* anything with it is orthogonal.

Comment: @DaveNewton " Is the location specific to the browser or specific to react?" clearly betrays a lack of understanding.  Also, implicit in the idea that knowledge is worth acquiring is the idea that you can do something with it, and there's really nothing you can do with the location of local storage data on a user's computer.  But my point wasn't to argue over the OP's understanding, my point was to discourage downvoting of a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get access to localStorage in React, you can just call `window.localStorage.[methodName]()` to get / set / remove just like in vanilla js.

There should be no difference whether you're using Vanilla JS, React or any other framework. LocalStorage exists on the `window`, that is to say, its global in the browser, so as long as your app is running in a browser that supports localStorage, then you can get to it via `window`.

Comment: OP is asking for the physical location, which is an implementation detail.