# How to access state in public file in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase background notification messages, therefore I had to put `firebase-messaging-sw.js` *file* in **public folder**. I need to access state, which determines language of the website inside `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. I am using `useContext` to manage state. Here is the code of `firebase-messaging-sw.js` :

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js");


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const messaging = firebase.messaging();


const openDatabase = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open('qapp-firebase-messages', 1);

    request.onerror = () => {
      console.error('Error opening IndexedDB database.');
      reject(request.error);
    };

    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      resolve(request.result);
    };

    request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;
      if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('messages')) {
        const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('messages', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
      }
    };
  });
};


const storeMessage = async (messageData) => {
  const db = await openDatabase();
  const transaction = db.transaction('messages', 'readwrite');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('messages');
  const request = objectStore.put(messageData);
  transaction.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('Error storing message in IndexedDB:', error);
  };
};

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log("backgroundmessages recieved")
  console.log(payload.data)
  storeMessage(payload.data);
});
```

There should be some way to connect to source code from public folder.

Answer (score 0):

we can not use `useState` or any other hook out side a react Component. but here you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to get selected language.

### Update

you need to use postMessage() back to the Worker's originating code, and have that code store the data in localStorage.

You should use localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem() to save and get data from local storage.

[Worker.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)

Pseudo code below, hoping it gets you started:

```
 // include your worker
 var myWorker = new Worker('YourWorker.js'),
   data,
   changeData = function() {
     // save data to local storage
     localStorage.setItem('data', (new Date).getTime().toString());
     // get data from local storage
     data = localStorage.getItem('data');
     sendToWorker();
   },
   sendToWorker = function() {
     // send data to your worker
     myWorker.postMessage({
       data: data
     });
   };
 setInterval(changeData, 1000)
```

Comment: You can't access localStorage or sessionStorage from file, which is in public folder.

Comment: use window.localStorage. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319607/20587701

Comment: it says window is not defined.

Comment: I researched about it and found that we can not use localstorage in serviceWorker file, but we can use Worker to call a function in which we can use localStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below modules to have the exact service in react src folder only:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";
```

Comment: All that code I have provided should be in public folder, otherwise it won't work. All I need is to import some state from source code in public file.